# setCollectEmail is not supported in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I'm trying to automatically create a form based on entries in a google spreadsheet. I want to set the form to automatically collect emails using the following code:

```
function createForm()  
{  
   var form = FormApp.create('New Form')  
                .setCollectEmail(true);

    //I have also tried form.setCollectEmail(true);  
}
```

Except when I run it, I get an error saying "This operation is not supported".

I'm referencing: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form

Thanks!
-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only collect the email if you are running Google Apps for Business/ Education/Domain.

See here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#collectsEmail()

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I did not see that line until now.